# How can I override the serialized name of each list item in a List<SomeStruct>() in c#?

Tags: c#, list, struct, generics, xmlserializer

I have a struct more or less like this:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Customer")]
public struct TCustomer
{
  string CustomerNo;
  string Name;
}
```

I sometimes serialize this this struct to XML as a single object, which works fine, but I also sometimes need to serialize a List<> of this struct.

I've used this to set the top level element name:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("Customers")]
public class CustomerList : List<TCustomer> { }
```

XmlSerializer however, insists on calling each list item TCustomer. How can I tell XmlSerializer to use the name Customer instead of TCustomer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank's for all the answers. The sollution to my specific problem however, turned out to be as simple as:

```
[XmlRoot("Customers")]
public class Customers
{
    [XmlElement("Customer")]
    public List<TCustomer> List = new List<TCustomer>();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Hope it helps

```
[XmlType("Customer")]
[XmlRoot("Customer")]
public struct TCustomer
{
    public string CustomerNo;
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Nice! It would be nice if you could explain, though?

Comment: Controls the XML schema that is generated when the attribute target is serialized by the XmlSerializer. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute.aspx

Comment: This is more proper - Initializes a new instance of the XmlTypeAttribute class and specifies the name of the XML type. - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/573s2dsz.aspx

Comment: +1 - I like this!  I didn't know you could use XmlType in that way to control the name when used in a complex type (like `List<TCustomer>`)

Answer (score 5):

The `XmlRoot` attribute only applies for the root element, so it doesn't apply for `TCustomer` when you are serializing `CustomerList`.

Without implementing your own serialization, I don't think you can change `TCustomer` to serialize as `Customer` within the `CustomerList` class.  But you can do something like this...

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("customerList")]
public class CustomerList 
{
    [XmlArray("customers")]
    [XmlArrayItem("customer")]
    public List<TCustomer> Customers { get; set; }
}
```

That should give you xml similar to:

```
<customerList>
   <customers>
      <customer />
      <customer />
      <customer />
   </customers>
</customerList>
```

This changes your CustomerList from a generic list, but it allows you to control your naming.

Comment: I have not yet seen a case where the accepted answer also works for serializing item names for standard types like `List<string> MyList`, this answer however is flexible enough to handle renaming child tag names in that particular case. Also if you only need to rename the list element tags, I have noticed that only the  `[XmlArrayItem("customer")]`is actually needed

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this at the class /struct level, but this is how I do it when I need to serialize a list inside a class.

```
    [XmlArray("ConfigurationList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Configuration")]
    private List<string> pConfigList = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `IXmlSerializable` in order to customize the way some object is serialized:

[IXmlSerializable Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)

Anyway, it seems that serializer calls `TCustomer` the type of items because this is the actual type of the `List` (`TCustomer` is ???, where ??? will be the actual type of the generic parameter type `TCustomer`).

I wouldn't change the way `XmlSerializer` serializes objects without implementing `IXmlSerializable` (I mean, avoid a post-serializing text replacement or whatever!).